# Как переделать if на switch при работе с vector в C++

Tags: c++

у меня есть вектор, я могу пробежаться по нему через for() и if()

```
vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5};

for(auto i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
{
   if(vec[i] == 1)
     //do smth...
   if(vec[i] == 2)
     //do smth...
   if(vec[i] == 3)
     //do smth...
   if(vec[i] == 4)
     //do smth...
   if(vec[i] == 5)
     //do smth...
}
```

как мне переделать это через конструкцию switch case?

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем минусовать. Незнание - не стигма.

Comment: @AK switch - это как основы с++, то что изучают в первую очередь. Поиск в поисковике по слову switch c++ - даст нужный результат, поэтому... вопрос как бы слишком общий. Думаю, что те кто серьезно долгое время писали на с++ находят вопрос неумесным.

Comment: @nick_n_a "то, что изучают систематическки", но на so редко сидят те, кто изучают что-то систематически. Кроме того, на so [не принято](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987) отправлять в поисковик.

Comment: @AK Но принято, и даже требуется, попытаться решить проблему самостоятельно. Очевидно, что эту проблему автор самостоятельно решить не пытался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i(0);i<vec.size();i++)
{
   switch(vec[i])
   {
       case 1:
       //do smth...
       break;

       case 2:
       //do smth...
       break;

       // etc

       default:
       //do smth...
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Код не равнозначный исходному. В `//do smth...` значение элементов вектора может измениться. Ну и сравнение знаковых с беззнаковыми на десерт.

Comment: @älёxölüt в целом Вы правы, просто я рассуждал, что человеку нужен обыкновенное исправление на switch.

Comment: Скорее всего так оно и есть, иначе бы ТС не поставил галочку. Но на не сразу заметные моменты было интересно обратить внимание.

Answer (score 3):

Учитывая, что в общем случае в `do smth` может присутствовать модификация элементов вектора, а также что каждый последующий `if` при отсутствии в `do smth` команд типа `break`, `return`, `continue` ... будет требовать проверки, эквивалентный код со `switch` будет достаточно странным (и всё равно содержать `if`):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    int visited = 0;

    again:
    switch(vec[i]) {
        case 1: if (visited >= 1) break; visited = 1; /* do smth... */ goto again;
        case 2: if (visited >= 2) break; visited = 2; /* do smth... */ goto again;
        case 3: if (visited >= 3) break; visited = 3; /* do smth... */ goto again;
        case 4: if (visited >= 4) break; visited = 4; /* do smth... */ goto again;
        case 5: if (visited >= 5) break; visited = 5; /* do smth... */ goto again;
    }
}
```

Можно подсунуть сюда макрос:

```
#define v(i) if (visited >= i) break; visited = i
```

Но это всё равно будет выглядеть не менее странно:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    int visited = 0;

    again:
    switch(vec[i]) {
        case 1: v(i); /* do smth... */ goto again;
        case 2: v(i); /* do smth... */ goto again;
        case 3: v(i); /* do smth... */ goto again;
        case 4: v(i); /* do smth... */ goto again;
        case 5: v(i); /* do smth... */ goto again;
    }
}
```

P.S. заодно, я заменил `int` на `size_t`, т.к. размер вектора всё-таки имеет беззнаковый тип.